# c# menuItem1 will not disable

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2008, .net-2.0

Is this wrong?

I always get "cb1 and firmware" even if my checkBox2 is checked. I also tried with just & instead of &&.

It was working fine before I had to add it into thread to get UI to update correctly.

```
 private void MyWorkerThread2()
            {
             if (this.IsChecked(checkBox1) && (this.IsChecked(checkBox2) && (myString == "86.09.0000")))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("cb1 and firmware and cb2");
                Prep.clean();
                startedimage();
                fscreate();
                wipefiles();
            }
            else if ((this.IsChecked(checkBox1) && (myString == "86.09.0000")))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("cb1 and firmware");
                Prep.clean();
                startedimage();
                wipefiles();
            }
            else if (myString == "86.09.0000") 
            {
                MessageBox.Show("firmware");
                if (myThread == null)
                {

                    Prep.clean();
                    startedimage();
                    myThread = new Thread(MyWorkerThread);
                    myThread.IsBackground = true;
                    myThread.Start();
                }
            }

            else
            {

                FactoryReset();
            }
        }



public delegate bool IsCheckedDelegate(CheckBox cb);
        public bool IsChecked(CheckBox cb)
        {
            if (cb.InvokeRequired)
            {
                return (bool)cb.Invoke(new IsCheckedDelegate(IsChecked), new Object[] { cb });
            }
            else
            {
                return cb.Checked;

            }
        }
```

Comment: Did you tried `this.IsChecked(checkBox1 == true)`?

Comment: Yes but I didn't work. 
Error 1 Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox' and 'bool'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I always get "cb1 and firmware" even if my checkBox2 is checked.

The fact that `checkBox2` is checked isn't going to change the fact that `checkBox1` is also checked and so the first `if` statement succeeds. If `checkBox1` wasn't checked, it would fall to the other sets.

It's not clear what you're trying to do here, but I would say the first two `if` statements need reversed.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you only want the first to be executed when checkBox2 is NOT checked.

Change:

```
if ((this.IsChecked(checkBox1) && (myString == "86.09.0000")))
```

To:

```
if ((this.IsChecked(checkBox1) && (!this.IsChecked(checkBox2) && (myString == "86.09.0000")))
```

There are four possibilities here:

```
none
cb1
cb2
cb1, cb2
```

Answer (score 1):

Try reordering the code

```
if (this.IsChecked(checkBox1) && (this.IsChecked(checkBox2) && (myString == "86.09.0000")))    
{
    MessageBox.Show("cb1 and firmware and cb2");
    Prep.clean();
    startedimage();
    fscreate();
    wipefiles();
}
else if ((this.IsChecked(checkBox1) && (myString == "86.09.0000")))
{
    MessageBox.Show("cb1 and firmware");
    Prep.clean();
    startedimage();
    wipefiles();
}
```